# PostGIS - Raster - update all values - what is prefered

Tags: postgis, raster

I have added the Raster support to my PostGIS database program. Now, I need to update all values in the raster (one band only) several times a day.

I have found and tested these two options

- Use `ST_SetValues` (http://postgis.net/docs/manual-2.1/RT_ST_SetValues.html)
- Use WKB and do `UPDATE table SET rast = 'wkb_data_string';` (code extracted from http://www.postgis.org/documentation/raster-doxygen/dd/d23/rt__api_8c-source.html)

Both methods works fine with same results, speeds according to my tests seems also almost the same (but I may have done some errors there).

What is a better way from those twos, or is there some third option?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think using ST_SetValues is better.  The reason is the wkb structure of raster may change in future version so your code may break at that point.  ST_SetValues since its a user facing function will always be updated to be inline with internal structure.

Also forgot to add -- that's an old ancient doxygen link when raster was separated (and www.postgis.org is not in use anymore) .  raster doxygen is now part of core postgis doxygen so use this instead:

http://postgis.net/docs/doxygen/2.1/dirs.html

Most up to date doxygen links are here:
http://postgis.net/development

Comment: Thank you... And if I "neglect" the point, that WKB may change, should I use WKB?

Comment: I would say whichever is faster and/or easiest to write.  If they are close I would go with easiest to write.